# What is a better pattern for implementing these features in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

We have a few features that follow very similar patterns:

1. User submits email address
2. User receives email with secret code
3. User redeems secret code to perform secure action

For example, our sign-up / registration feature follows this pattern. User submits email address, receives email, then uses secret code to create password & user account. Another example is password reset. User submits email address, receives email, then uses secret code to change password and access user account.

**Pattern #1**

We could have 1 controller that manages each feature individually. So, for example, a SignUpController that handles all related actions (sending email, redeeming code, and creating password). Then we could have a PasswordResetController that also handles sending the email, redeeming the code, and changing the password.

**Pattern #2**

An alternative would be to have the actions split across controllers. In this pattern, we would have a SendEmailController that would send emails for both features, a CodeRedemptionController that would handle code redemptions for both features, and a PasswordController that would handle password operations for both features.

Which is a better approach and why? Our main goals are to achieve high code simplicity, clarity / discoverability, and DRYness. I can see advantages and disadvantages with both patterns.

**Pattern #1 advantages**

All code pertaining to the feature is kept in one place. Passing data from one action to another using TempData dictionary is easier to understand, and the flow of the feature is described by a single controller.

**Pattern #1 disadvantages**

Dependency injection. Each feature controller would need dependencies injected for email sender, account manager (MembershipProvider interface wrapper), as well as various repositories. When using constructor injection, the constructor would have a lot of arguments.

The advantages and disadvantages of Pattern #2 would be the opposite. We could simplify dependencies for the controllers, but the features would be spread across multiple controllers, blurring the clarity of what features the app as a whole is trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there an option to have only one AccountController (similar to Visual Studio gives you while creating a new application)? Seems it's not difficult to manage all operations about users. For sending email I could suggest using some EmailService class having some email templates. Is that too simple?

Comment: @Shymep, we already have email templates and an EmailService class. In fact, both EmailTemplateRepository and EmailService would be dependencies for the send email component of each of these features. Putting all of this stuff in a single AccountController would make that controller extremely bloated. I would like to keep different account-related responsibilities separated somehow.

Comment: I agree with Shymep. Keep user account stuff in one controller if possible. If you're sticking to the MVC pattern (controllers skinny, models fat) then your controllers shouldn't be "extremely bloated".

Comment: So you don't consider having 20+ action methods in a single controller as bloat, even if each method is lean? What if it meant you had to inject more than 5 dependencies in the controller constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single account controller to manage all of the related user management functions. This controller would be the user's access point to handle these types of features.

Then I would separate the separate logic you mentioned into different model classes that would be called by that controller as needed. Examples:

```
/models/EmailManager.cs
/models/PasswordManager.cs
/models/SecretCodeGenerator.cs
/models/AccountManager.cs
```

This would allow you to have a consolidated url syntax. It would keep you from having many controllers with only 1 method. And it would keep you from having a lot of model type logic in the controllers.

```
www.mydomain.com/account/signup/
www.mydomain.com/account/confirm/
www.mydomain.com/account/resetpassword/
```

(with custom routes, you could even remove the /account/ part if you wish)

However, I might be tempted to create a custom controller to handle redeeming of secret codes. (redeemController) This way you could control access to much of the accountController to authorized/existing users only, whereas the redeem controller (depending on your design) may be open to anonymous for new customers.

Finally, having most of the logic in the model classes makes them much more test friendly.